# Подгрузка файла в память

Tags: c++, массивы, хранение-данных

Есть большой файл с двумерным массивом. Весь массив целиком загружать в память, я думаю, не стоит (ну очень большой массив). Периодически нужны кусочки данных из разных частей массива. Как это лучше организовать?

Есть вариант держать `fstream` все время открытым и выбирать данные используя `seekg()`. Будет ли в таком случае весь файл загружен в память?

Comment: Какая ОС и "очень большой" это сколько ? Вообще есть замечательная функция `mmap` которая отражает файл в память. При этом ваша программа работает с памятью, а ОС тем же механизмом каким обслуживает swap подкачивает фрагменты файла по мере необходимости и так же автоматически записывает на диск изменения произошедшие в памяти. Кроме того чтение файла происходит быстрее, потому как исключается фаза копирования из буферов ОС в буфер программы

Comment: Кросс ОС :) Пара гигов. Но мне уже дали нужную инфу. Спасибо всем.

Comment: @reload  фигню вам дали. Вы собираетесь взять на себя функцию страничной подкачки (mmap), которая уже реализована в современных ОС самым наилучшим образом. Не городите велосипед!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Файл нужно отобразить на оперативную память (mmap в unix, CreateFileMapping в Windows). Тогда при обращении к нему, ОС будет сама подтягивать с диска нужные куски (причем самым оптимальным образом). В том случае, если физической памяти будет недоставать, ОС выбросит эти страницы из нее (что не займет практически никакого времени), и не будет их долго и мучительно сливать в файл подкачки.

Answer (score 2):

> Будет ли в таком случае весь файл загружен в память?

Нет, не будет. Если бы открытие файла с помощью `std::fstream` требовало загрузки всего содержимого файла в память, то большие файлы открывались бы ну очень долго, а это не так.

Поэтому предложенную Вами идею вполне можно использовать для реализации.